# how to do a wordpress link block?

Tags: css, wordpress

does anyone have an idea on the css that would turn the following in to a linked block?

```
<div class="one_third"> 
<?php
//The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=15');
    //The Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
<div class="entry">
<p><a style="display: block;" rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());?></a></p>
```

Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the generated html and your css?

Comment: What do you mean by a "linked block"? Do you want the wole dive to work like a link?

Comment: @David yes, I'd like everything inside the "one_third" div wrapper to be a link. See below for code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Sotiris

Sorry for the late reply only get to work on this site after working hours.

```
 <div class="one_third">    
    <h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/edinburghshiatsuclinic/news-offers/news-letters-suday-test-post/." rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to News Letters Suday test post">News Letters Suday test post</a></h2>
<small>May 15th, 2011</small>
  <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://localhost:8888/edinburghshiatsuclinic/news-offers/news-letters-suday-test-post/." title="News Letters Suday test post"><img width="190" height="140" src="http://localhost:8888/edinburghshiatsuclinic/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/front-page3-200x147.jpg" class="attachment-medium-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="front-page3" title="front-page3" /></a></div>    <div class="entry">

    <p><a style="display: block;" rel="bookmark" href="http://localhost:8888/edinburghshiatsuclinic/news-offers/news-letters-suday-test-post/.">Suspendisse tempus semper dignissim. Pellentesque ac tempus ligula. Aenean eu nisi eu mi consequat vehicula venenatis et leo. Praesent ornare aliquam ultricies. Nunc justo tellus, varius quis viverra a, scelerisque non justo. Suspendisse leo turpis, elementum in dignissim sed, facilisis &hellip; Continue reading &rarr;</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the code you posted, everything in the div is a link already. If you want clicking anywhere on the div to work like a link, you'll need to use Javascript--can't really wrap a block-level element (`<div>`) in an inline element (`<a>`).

Here is a jQuery way to do that:

`$('#one_third').click(
    function(){
        $(this).find('h2 a').click();
    });`

It just says "when you click on the div with id `'one_third'`, look for the element `'h2 a'` in it and trigger a click on that element. (I narrowed it down to just one of the links, if you didn't do that, if you just said (`'a'`), it would click all the links. Which could be interesting as well.)

Comment: Thanks David, 
I tried
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function(){
  $('.one_third').click( function(){ $(this).find('h2 a').click(); });
 </script>
 but no luck?

Comment: I see you have changed `#one_third` to `.one_third`, which is correct for your code. You have also wrapped the function inside of `jQuery(function(){`, I presume because Wordpress can have conflicts with other libraries. If you do that, make sure you are closing the function correctly. Try adding another `});` at the end, like this: 
`<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function(){ 
$('.one_third').click( 
 function(){ 
 $(this).find('h2 a').click(); 
 });
}); 
</script>`

Comment: Of course, make sure you are linking to a working version of jQuery.
Something I like to do, if you are using Firebug, Safari, or Chrome, is add `console.log($(this));` to the code (here I would put it in the innermost function). If it logs an error or something unexpected it can help you find what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your tips David, I got it sorted in the end by changing the structure of the layout to something a bit more easy to handle. Sorry for the late reply I don't think stack is letting me kn ow when I get replies.